# When is $(a-1)(a-b)/b$ a positive integer?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b \geq 1$ be positive integers and $S \subset \mathbb{N}^2$ where
$$ S = \{(a,b)\in\mathbb{N}^2 : (a-1)(a-b)/b \text{ is a positive integer} \}. $$ 
How does one go about determining all the elements of $S$?

I have some observations below.
Since $(a-1)(a-b)$ is positive we need $a>b$. As $(a-1)(a-b)/b$ is a positive integer, $(a-1)(a-b)$ is a positive multiple of $b$. Say $(a-1)(a-b)=bn$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}^+$.

So then expanding $a^2-ab-a+b = bn$ and so $a^2-a=a(a-1)=b(n+a+1)$ is a multiple of $b$ where $n+a+1 \geq a+2$.

<s>As $a$ and $a-1$ are relatively prime this implies that $a$ or $a-1$ is a multiple of $b$.</s>

I'm not sure if I'm any closer to a better description of $S$ however... Is there a simple description, in terms of $a$ and $b$, of $S$?

Comment: You made a mistake: $3\times 2$ is a multiple of $6$, but neither $3$ nor $2$ is: From the fact that $b$ divides $a(a-1)$ you cannot conclude that $b$ divides $a$ or $b$ divides $a-1$. (You could reach this conclusion if you know that $b$ is a prime number, for example.)

Comment: Try the example $a=9, b=6$

Comment: The idempotents mod $b$ can be devised from $b$'s factorization via Sun-Ze (aka CRT).

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: I see the mistake now. As in Mark's example $9\cdot 8=72$ is a multiple of $6$ but neither $8$ or $9$ are.

Comment: Note, you should get $a(a-1)=(a-1+n)b$ - I have adjusted my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you should get $$a(a-1)=(a-1+n)b$$

Identify $n$ via a factor $c\gt a-1$ of $a(a-1)$, so that $n=c-(a-1)$

So you are looking for large factors ($\gt a-1$) of $a(a-1)$.

$c=a$ is always such a factor, leading to the solution $n=1$, $b=a-1$.

---

Original answer based on mistaken analysis in question

Once you have $$a(a-1)=(a+1+n)b$$ concentrate on what $n$ might be given $a$.

If $c$ is any positive integer with $c\gt a+1$ which is also a factor of $a(a-1)$, then set $n=c-a-1$.

Any such factor leads to a value of $b$, and any value of $b$ corresponds to such a factor.